# Should /etc/hosts contain the domain name or the FQDN?

Tags: networking, dns, internet, hosts

If I want to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` to resolve all traffic for `example.com` to `1.2.3.4`, do I need to add

```
1.2.3.4    example.com
1.2.3.4    www.example.com
1.2.3.4    smtp.example.com
1.2.3.4    pop.example.com
...
```

Or will just adding

```
1.2.3.4    example.com
```

suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to specify each and every subdomain. If that is not what you want, you should look into installing a real DNS server (e.g. bind9).

This is rather easy to check by first adding just `example.com` to `/etc/hosts` and then do

```
ping -c 2 example.com
ping -c 2 www.example.com
```

The first will succeed with the provided IP address. The second will go to `93.184.216.119` (the IP address in the internet for www.example.com)

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/hosts` is/was the precursor to the DNS system from when the Internet was in it's infancy.  It's still used today for situation such as when you want to resolve a small number of local systems or in a development setup where you haven't set up DNS.

You place all hostnames that you want to resolve to an IP address in it.  You can allocate multiple names to one IP address as the `localhost` line in most distros have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

If you want to add `1.2.3.4` to be your webserver, which is called `www.example.com` and also access it via a shorter `www` then add:

```
1.2.3.4   www www.example.com
```

In your instance, you can place all the names on one line:

```
1.2.3.4 www.example.com smtp.example.com pop.example.com
```

The order in which your system resolves these names (`/etc/hosts` or DNS first) can be configured in the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`)

But remember, `/etc/hosts` only works from your machine.  If you have a few systems, editing `/etc/hosts` on each can become unwieldly.