# Absolute domain names in /etc/hosts?

Tags: rhel, resolution, hosts, etc

I have a RHEL7.0 host which has this standard entry in `/etc/hosts/`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

So resolving `localhost.localdomain` works:

```
$ ping localhost.localdomain
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

But trying to resolve the absolute version of the same fails:

```
$ ping localhost.localdomain.
ping: unknown host localhost.localdomain.
```

And in general, trying to resolve absolute FQDNs against relative `/etc/hosts` entries fails. Now, if I change the entry in `/etc/hosts` to have a trailing period, I can then resolve the absolute FQDN. But then I can no longer resolve the relative FQDN. Seems if I want both absolute and relative forms to resolve, I have to explicitly include both forms of the FQDN in `/etc/hosts`.

Is this odd behavior described in an RFC or standard somewhere so I can understand it better? Is it configurable somehow?

Comment: What does your nsswitch.conf file have for hosts?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: `hosts:      files dns myhostname`

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166083/

this is likely not specified anywhere, but just an implementation detail of resolver library (on modern systems, nss_files module).